# Should "differentiate" be plural in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence

*What we know how to do and what we have done differentiate us from others.* 

 or 
*What we know how to do and what we have done differentiates us from others.*

Can anyone explain to me which is correct and why?

Comment: Not related to this question.

Comment: Answered at Answered at [“There is a lot of food and fruit” vs. “there are a lot of food and fruit” {duplicate}](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141192/there-is-a-lot-of-food-and-fruit-vs-there-are-a-lot-of-food-and-fruit/141206#141206) [see 'coordinated noun groups']

Answer (score 1):

Only nouns have plurals, and *differentiate* is a verb, so it is never plural.

What you are referring to is the third person 's', which is applied when the subject is *he, she*, or *it*:

*I walk*
*you walk*
*he/she/it walks*
*etc*

In your example, the subject is "What we know how to do and what we have done", which is an *it*, hence:

*What we know how to do and what we have done differentiates us from others*

is correct.

Comment: I disagree. Depending on exactly how the speaker sees "it" (sorry! :), the things we *know how to do* and the things we *have done* might represent two significantly different categories which could reasonably be attached to a plural verb form. And even if there's only one "what", it can still reference multiple things - *"What I upvote on ELU **are** those questions I find interesting"*.

Comment: ... quite true. Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast, but bacon and eggs are both in short supply.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I can see how it may be possible to turn the subject into two subjects and call it 'they', but in the absence of a comma or any other device separating them that seems to be stretching it somewhat. To steal Edwin's example *"bacon, and eggs, differ from carrots"* compared with *"bacon and eggs differs from toast and marmalade"*

Comment: To be honest I find OP's example a bit "odd", since for most purposes in such a context you'd assume *things we have done* are just a subcategory of *things we know how to do* (which includes things we haven't got around to doing *yet*, and those we just don't *want* to do even though we know how). It would work better for me if we reversed the two sub-elements - which would draw attention to the *difference* between past achievements and the (potentially much greater) things we might accomplish in the future. *And* which would encourage me to refer to them in the plural.

Comment: I guess if it wasn't odd it wouldn't be a question! Interesting that you say reversing them would make it more of a 'they'. I would need a comma for that. I wonder why? I can see "I am going to buy bacon and eggs" being different to "I am going to buy eggs and bacon", but only because of the sociocultural knowledge of bacon and eggs for breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of whether to use the ‘s’ changes the meaning of the sentence. The answer is thus, it depends on what you’re trying to communicate. Do you want to imply that “what we know how to do” and “what we have done” are two different sets of things? Or one and the same?