# Correct grammar for talking about multiple, single nouns

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I'd like to know the definitions of both mathematical terms "consistency" and "completeness".  Would I ask

- "What **are** consistency and completeness?" (i.e., the two nouns are singular, but together they're a collection of things) or
- "What **is** consistency and completeness?" (i.e., we can distribute the "What is" to read "What is consistency and what is completeness?")

Thanks.

Comment: This already has an answer at [There is a lot of food and fruit vs there are a lot of food and fruit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141192/there-is-a-lot-of-food-and-fruit-vs-there-are-a-lot-of-food-and-fruit/141206#141206) and other threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What are X and Y?* asks for separate definitions of each term. It's like *What is X and what is Y?*.

*What is X and Y?* treats them as a single collective concept, and asks for a definition of that one thing.